# Need help adding Email Validation and hiding form after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am new to PHP and am having trouble with adding email validation and then hiding the form after pressing the submit button. I have an error.php, thankyou.php and formmail.php. The PHP code below is that of formmail.php. I just don't know what to write for email validation for this specific code. I've tried copying some PHP codes from other sites but it just doesn't match up with my code. And as far as hiding the form after submit, I really don't know what to do with that.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="contact">
        <div id="contact-left">
        <form id="ajaxsubmit" action="formmail.php" method="post">
<div class="form">
    <div class="formblock">
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="required txt" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="formblock">
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <input name="email" class="required txt" type="text" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="formblock">
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" id="comments"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="subbtn" value="Submit"  />
    <div id="message"></div>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
    <?php
// Insert your email/web addresses and correct paths
$mailto = 'myemail@email.com' ;
$from = "http://website.com" ;
$formurl = "http://website.com/formmail.php" ;
$errorurl = "http://website.com/error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "http://website.com/thankyou.php" ;

// Place Your Form info here...
$firstname = ($_POST['name']);
$email_from = ($_POST['email']);
$comments = ($_POST['comments']);

// Check If Empty
if (empty($firstname)) {
   header( "Location: $errorurl" );
   exit ;
}
// Add more Validation/Cleaning here...


// Place your Corresponding info here...
$message =

    "Name: $firstname\n\n" .
    "Email: $email_from\n\n" .
    "Comment: $comments\n\n"
;

// Leave Alone
mail($mailto, $from, $message,
    "From: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep );
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;

?>
```

Please let me know if you can assist me or need any other information from my html.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what Code of jQuery validation you tried?

Comment: Hiding the form is going to be purely JavaScript. Preferably receive a confirmed response from AJAX that will trigger the removal of the form, also disable the button until you receive the response to prevent duplicate submissions.

Comment: `filter_var()` is the simplest way to validate the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate email in php, follow [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php),

```
if (filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_from) email address is considered valid.";
}
```

To hide the form, using jquery,

```
$(document).on('submit', '#ajaxsubmit',function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

or using pure javascript,

Change HTML,

```
<form id="ajaxsubmit" action="formmail.php" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

and JS

```
function myFunction(){
    var form = document.getElementById("ajaxsubmit");
    form.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Optimus! The last two codes worked to hide the form. However, I want it to hide the form but display the thankyou.php. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @user3431886 The email validation also works. If its on a different page just redirect the user to that page. `header("Location: ".$thankyouurl);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I just moved the <div id="message"></div> outside of the form div and it displays the message and hides the form. Thank you for your quick help!